# AMQP handshake timeout error while deploying AWS Corda Enterprise Template

Tags: corda

I am deploying AWS Corda Enterprise Template. The Quick start deployed the stack as per the defined CloudFormation template. I can see 2 AWS instances, up and running as Corda nodes, in Hot-Cold setup with a load balancer.
However the Log for Corda node has following ERROR related to AMQP communication.

> [ERROR] 2018-10-18T05:47:55,743Z [Thread-3
>   (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 -
>   AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}

What can be possible reason for this error? This error keeps on occurring after a certain time interval. So it looks like some connectivity issue to me.

Note: The load balancer shows the status of this AWS Corda instances as healty (In Service). So I believe the Corda node has booted up successfully.

Comment: Hey I asked the staff from Red Hat and they recommended to switch to two-way (client-side) connections if you are using the one-way(server-site) connections. For more details about how to edit the TLS parameters, you may refer to Security docs [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.1/html/using_amq_broker/security#tls).

Answer (score 2):

The ERROR message isn't necessarily tied to AMQP. Perhaps you were confused by the "AMQ" in the error ID (AMQ224088)?

In any event, this error indicates that something on the network is connecting to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker, but it's not completing any protocol handshake. This is commonly seen with, for example, load balancers that do a health check by creating a socket connection without sending any real data just to see if the port is open on the target machine.

Comment: Agreed. This is generally a harmless error message.

Comment: finally, I know the reason! +1